# Best method for merging rotation data

Tags: navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two sensors providing a z-axis rotation estimate on a two-wheeled differential drive platform:

1. motor encoders
2. a compass-aligned gyroscope

Does it make sense to use some algorithm to merge these two, or should I just rely on the gyro? If I should combine them, what's the proper algorithm to use (Kalman filter, Complementary filter, simple moving average, etc)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258010/best-method-for-merging-rotation-data/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2017-03-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you to use an Extended Kalman Filter. It can provide an estimation of the robot's orientation by filtering both wheel's and gyro's drifts.

---

Originally posted by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) with karma: 396 on 2017-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2017-03-28**:
Is there a simple implementation you can recommend, preferably that could run on an Arduino? All the ones I've found seem terribly complicated, and assume you're trying to merge two three-dimensional vectors representing accelerometer and gryoscope readings, not simple scalars, as I'm trying to do.

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2017-03-29**:
The implementation of the EKF strongly depends on the application. If the state you have to estimate is just the position of the robot you can use something like [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6614621/#full-text-section). The EKF should work without problems on Arduino.